# Rust macro to generate a macro

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm writing some macros that are all really similar (MWE the actual ones are much larger):

```rust
macro_rules! var1 {
  () => {some_func(some_enum::Var1, vec![])};
  ($($e:expr),*) => {some_func(some_enum::Var1, vec![$($s),*])};
}
macro_rules! var2 {
  () => {some_func(some_enum::Var2, vec![])};
  ($($e:expr),*) => {some_func(some_enum::Var2, vec![$($s),*])};
}
```

I instead decided to try different brackets

```rust
macro_rules! var {
  () => {some_func(some_enum::Var1, vec![])};
  ($($e:expr),*) => {some_func(some_enum::Var1, vec![$($s),*])};
  [] => {some_func(some_enum::Var2, vec![])};
  [$($e:expr),*] => {some_func(some_enum::Var2, vec![$($s),*])};
}
```

which didn't work. This would have been my preferred method to do this so if you know how to do this that's be greatly appreciated.

I instead tried to use a macro to generate the other macros:

```rust
macro_rules! generator {
  ($t:ident, $s:expr) => {
    macro_rules! $t {
      () => {some_func($s:expr, vec![])};
      ($($e:expr),*) => {some_func($s:expr, vec![$($s),*])};
    }
  };
}
generator!(var1, some_enum::Var1);
generator!(var2, some_enum::Var2);
```

This gives me the error "attempted to repeat an expression containing no syntax variables matched as repeating at this depth" andx I don't know what it means.

Comment: In your macros you sometimes use `$s` when only `$e` is defined. In the last attempt you have a `$s:expr` where I would have expected `$s` or `$e` not sure what exactly your macro is supposed to do there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting means that you use the repeat syntax `$(),*` without a syntax variable in it, which you see when you look at the full error message:

```
error: attempted to repeat an expression containing no syntax variables matched as repeating at this depth
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
10 |       ($($e:expr),*) => {some_func($s:expr, vec![$($e),*])};
   |         ^^^^^^^^^
```

The problem is you try to use the special syntax to define syntax variables inside of a macro where it has some different special meaning.
You can get around it by simply escaping the `$` that you do not wish to expand on the first macro invocation:

```rust
macro_rules! generator {
  ($t:ident, $s:expr) => {
    macro_rules! $t {
      () => {some_func($s, vec![])};
      ($$($$e:expr),*) => {some_func($s, vec![$$($$e),*])};
    }
  }
}
```

But [`macro_metavar_expr`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/83527) isn't stable yet so you have to add `#![feature(macro_metavar_expr)]` at the top of your crate and compile with a nightly compiler.

Note: added `;` after the macro branches and fixed some other syntax errors in there as well.